# How to using FakeAsync with testWidgets?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am trying to use `FakeAsync` from Dart `quiver`  library to mock the clock of a `CountDownTimer`.
However, when I await any async function inside the run method, it hangs.

```
testWidgets('Resend OTP', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await FakeAsync().run((async) async {
    final countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
      new Duration(seconds: 30),
      new Duration(seconds: 1),
      stopwatch: FakeStopwatch(
          () => async.getClock(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0)).now().millisecondsSinceEpoch, 1000),
    );
    print(countDownTimer.remaining);
    print(countDownTimer.isRunning);
    await tester.pumpWidget(Container());

  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it,
I am going to post it here anyways in case somebody needs the answer in the future:

```
testWidgets('Resend OTP Test concept', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final fakeAsync = FakeAsync();
    fakeAsync.run((async) async {
      final countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
        new Duration(seconds: 30),
        new Duration(seconds: 1),
        stopwatch: FakeStopwatch(
            () => async.getClock(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0)).now().millisecondsSinceEpoch, 1000),
      );
      print(countDownTimer.remaining);
      print(countDownTimer.isRunning);
      await tester.pumpWidget(Container());
//      expect(true, false);

    });
    fakeAsync.flushMicrotasks();
  });
```

The trick is to create a variable for the `FakeAsync` then synchronously call  `fakeAsync.flushMicrotasks();`

Comment: BTW, `testWidgets` already executes its body within a `FakeAsync` zone, and you can advance its clock with `tester.pump()`.

Comment: But how do you use that FakeAsync zone to control the clock of this countDown timer?